# MySQL archive data...what to do when it's too big

Tags: php, mysql

I use an `INSERT INTO` & `DELETE FROM` combination in a PHP script to take data out of an operational MySQL table and put into into an archive table.

The archive table has gotten too big. Even though no day-to-day operations are performed on it, mysqldump chokes when we back up (error 2013):

`Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table 'some_table' at row: 1915554`

What can I do? Should my PHP script move it to another DB (how?)? Is it okay to keep the large table in the operational db?--in that case, how do I get around the mysqldump issue?

Thanks!

Comment: do you use the mysql or mysqli driver?

Comment: @Book of Zeus - not sure, but this also happens at the shell

Comment: you mean shell using the `/usr/bin/mysql`? (I had the same problem and i fixed it using mysqli)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you by chance dumping using memory buffering and running out of swap and physical RAM?  If so, you can try dumping row by row instead.

Try adding --quick to your mysqldump statement.

According to the documentation, you should combine --single-transaction with --quick.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: tried it with `mysqldump --opt --single-transaction --quick -u someuser -p` and got the same error

Comment: How much data is in the table and how many rows does it have?  Also are you sure you aren't running out of disk space?

Comment: This MySQL bug suggests checking your timeout settings: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30809

Comment: I'm sure I have enough disk space. I get a `ERROR 2013 (HY000)` when I run `SELECT COUNT(*)` so I'm not sure about rows. The error says it crashes near row 2 million. I deleted that row and same thing

Comment: You could also try partitioning your backup using multiple calls and the --where parameter.  Although that seems like a hack.

Comment: i changed the timeout settings and no luck. i'll look into your partitioning idea and try to learn

Comment: +1 and this is the answer I accept. It turned out not to be my problem but from researching what I thought the problem was (too big of a table), @Will's recommendation for --single-transaction and --quick is correct. I'll post my answer for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 1):

Look for @Will's answer for a 2013 Error code due to a table being oversized.

That, however, turned out not to be my problem. When I ran a `SELECT` where giving it a `WHERE id>500000 AND id<1000000` (example), I quickly found out that a section of my data had been corrupted.

Because of this I couldn't copy the table content over, I couldn't back up the table (or the database) using `mysqldump`, I could even say `DELETE FROM` to get rid of the corrupted rows.

Instead I used `CREATE TABLE some_tbl_name SELECT * FROM corrupted_table WHERE id>500000 AND id<1000000` and then once I had the data that wasn't corrupt saved into another table, I was able to drop the corrupted table and create a new one.

I'm not accepting my own answer because Will's is correct, but if anyone runs into the same issue, I've posted it here.

Answer (score 1):

```
 mysqldump --opt --max_allowed_packet=128M base_de_datos > bd.sql
```

it works for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try `--var_max_allowed_packet=???` and `--var_net_buffer_length=???`

You can also try disabling extended inserts: `--skip-extended-insert`

But this is assuming your diagnosis of too large of a table is correct.

Just how big is this table?

Comment: the diagnosis may be incorrect. ironically i get a `ERROR 2013 (HY000)` when I `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Answer (score 0):

As for the second issue, try logging directly into the MySQL server and running `mysqldump` from there, preferably writing the dump to a local filesystem, but a network connection moving plain data is far more reliable than any SQL connection.

Comment: I'm also trying the linux shell. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Shell or GUI, makes no difference.  Just so it is running directly on the same machine as the server so that there is no network connection between them.